# How to add widgets to DevOps project standard(default) Overview Dashboard using REST API

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to add widgets to the standard(default) overview dashboard using the rest API (PAT). basically I want to update default overview dashboard and add widgets to it. while doing this, REST API call is adding new overview dashboard instead of updating existing overview dashboard

**Documentation **: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/dashboard/widgets/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP

**Method**: PUT/PATCH
URL : https://dev.azure.com/TenantN/DemoProject/_apis/dashboard/dashboards/e63247c4-b069-4bfe-ad1f-6fe609579629?api-version=7.1-preview.2

Body JSON:

```
{
    "position": 2,
    "name": "Individual 2",
    "description": "TestDB3",
    "eTag": "3",
    "refreshInterval": 0,
    "dashboardScope": "project",
    "widgets": {
        "name": "TestSQ",
        "position": {
            "row": 1,
            "column": 1
        },
        "size": {
            "rowSpan": 1,
            "columnSpan": 1
        },
        "settings": "",
        "settingsVersion": {
            "major": 1,
            "minor": 0,
            "patch": 0
        },
        "contributionId": "ms.vss-dashboards-web.Microsoft.VisualStudioOnline.Dashboards.QueryScalarWidget"
    }
}
```

The proper way to update existing overview dashboard using rest API

Answer (score 0):

*You can add a widget in an existing dashboard in the following way-*

I have used the below URL to add widget in an existing dashboard-

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/dashboard/dashboards/{dashboardId}/widgets?api-version=7.1-preview.2
```

**`Request Body`**

```
{
"name": "Other Links",

"position": {
"row": 1,
"column": 1
},

"size": {
"rowSpan": 1,
"columnSpan": 2
},

"settings": null,
"settingsVersion": {
"major": 1,
"minor": 0,
"patch": 0
},

"dashboard": {
"eTag": "18"
},

"contributionId": "ms.vss-dashboards-web.Microsoft.VisualStudioOnline.Dashboards.OtherLinksWidget"
}
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

**`Dashboard:`**

[image]

**Update**

*We can add widgets in Team dashboard as well in the following way-*

**`Get Request`**

To check if the Team dashboard is present in the given Team.

*URL-*

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/dashboard/dashboards/{dashboardId}?api-version=7.1-preview.3
```

[image]

Use the above Team dashboard Id and the same team name while making POST request.

*URL-*

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/dashboard/dashboards/{dashboardId}/widgets?api-version=7.1-preview.2
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ikhtesam Afrin for reply.
  
I tried with same configuration but its not working for me. I am getting below error

{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "VS402410: This dashboard no longer exists or you do not have permissions to view it. ID: a758d5be-6501-4304-ad8c-2248cfdbcea9",
    "typeName": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Dashboards.WebApi.DashboardDoesNotExistException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Dashboards.WebApi",
    "typeKey": "DashboardDoesNotExistException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 3000
}

Comment: Please check the dashboard I'd which you are passing in the url is still exists

Comment: Have you provided manage dashboard permission to your PAT

Comment: 1. Dashboard is still exist.
2. PAT has full access

Comment: can you provide me a screenshot of your Post request and the request body?

Comment: Can you try once creating a new dashboard and try to add the widget in that dashboard

Comment: Thanks Ikhtesam Afrin for reply.

I tried with same configuration but its not working for me. Please guide me on this issue

Postman request to get default overview dashboard id

Get Request  [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6HZg.png) _italic_ **bold** `code` 

Then sent same post request to add the widget to overview dashboard

Post request

 [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rrqx.png) _italic_ **bold** `code`

Comment: please share your post request Body and can you try to create a new dashboard and then add the widget in that dashboard

Comment: can you run [this](https://i.imgur.com/Ikl2Ta0.png) with your dashboard id and share the output here? Because in my case, I am getting the same error while sending POST request when that particular dashboard is not exist/deleted

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
In my case dashboard is present.
Get Request :
https://dev.azure.com/RawTenant/TestProject/_apis/dashboard/dashboards?api-version=7.1-preview.3
Response : 
{
    "count": 1,
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "a758d5be-6501-4304-ad8c-2248cfdbcea9",
            "name": "Overview",    "description": "",  "refreshInterval": 0,"position": 1,
            "eTag": "1", "groupId": "6e7a26bf-0ac0-47c5-a37f-b5f16387413e","ownerId": "6e7a26bf-0ac0-47c5-a37f-b5f16387413e",
            "dashboardScope": "project_Team",       
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Post Request : https://dev.azure.com/RawTenant/TestProject/_apis/dashboard/dashboards/a758d5be-6501-4304-ad8c-2248cfdbcea9/widgets?api-version=7.1-preview.2

 Post Body :

{
    "name": "TestSQ",
    "position": {
        "row": 2,
        "column": 1
    },
    "size": {
        "rowSpan": 1,
        "columnSpan": 1
    },
    "settings": "",   
    "contributionId": "ms.vss-dashboards-web.Microsoft.VisualStudioOnline.Dashboards.QueryScalarWidget"
}

Comment: is it a Team dashboard or project dashboard?

Comment: 2nd Post body JSON

{
    "name": "TestSQ",
    "position": {
        "row": 2,
        "column": 1
    },
    "size": {
        "rowSpan": 1,
        "columnSpan": 1
    },
    "settings": "",
    "settingsVersion": {
        "major": 1,
        "minor": 0,
        "patch": 0
    },
    "dashboard": {
        "eTag": "9"
    },
    "contributionId": "ms.vss-dashboards-web.Microsoft.VisualStudioOnline.Dashboards.QueryScalarWidget"
}

Comment: seems like it is a Team Dashboard then use `POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/dashboard/dashboards/{dashboardId}/widgets?api-version=7.1-preview.2`, pass the team name as well in the Post URL. It will work

Comment: Thanks for your reply
Yes its Team Dashboard
I tried by passing team name or team Id in URL, and getting below error
 
 "message": "The team with id '89440a6d-8834-4808-ba48-aad95f72fb4f' does not exist, or you do not have permission to access it.",
    "typeName": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi.TeamNotFoundException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi",
    "typeKey": "TeamNotFoundException",

Comment: can you give me a screenshot of how you are passing team name or team id in post request?

Comment: Thanks for your reply..

Please find details below as requested:

Get Team Request : [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA8qh.png) _italic_ **bold** 

Post Request with team name : [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYvVv.png) _italic_ **bold** 

Post Request with team id: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meX82.png) _italic_ **bold**

Comment: Sorry – Ikhtesam Afrin
 
But my issue is not still resolved.

Comment: what error you are getting, have you referred my updated answer?

Comment: Yes, I have checked your updated answer, I am getting same error as previous 

error "message": "The team with id '89440a6d-8834-4808-ba48-aad95f72fb4f' does not exist, or you do not have permission to access it.", "typeName": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi.TeamNotFoundException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi", "typeKey": "TeamNotFoundException

Kindly check my previous comments, there L have uploaded the screen shots.

Comment: can you share the screenshot of how you are fetching the Team dashboard id?

Comment: Kindly  find the fetch Team dashboard id.

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7T37Q.png)

Comment: You are incorrectly fetching the dashboard id you should do something like this `Get https://dev.azure.com/RawTenant/DemoProject/DemoProject Team/_apis/dashboard/dashboards?api-version=7.1-preview.3`.  I believe in your case Organization name is *RawTenant*, Project Name is *DemoProject* and the team name is *DemoProject Team*. If these information are correct then you use the `https://dev.azure.com/RawTenant/DemoProject/DemoProject Team/_apis/dashboard/dashboards?api-version=7.1-preview.3` to get the dashboard id which will be used in Post request later